# How to fix this Eslint warning in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I'm a beginner and I read the [Eslint docs](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-expressions) but can't understand how to refactor my code so the warning go away.

Here's an image:

[image]

The code is basically simple: and at `authUser.roles.includes(ROLES.A...` the warning comes.

```
function onClick() {
    const { authUser } = props;
    authUser.roles.includes(ROLES.ANON) ? openSignin() : openDashboard();
}

function openSignin() {
    props.showDash({
        open: true,
        closeDashboard,
    });
}

function openDashboard() {
    navigate('/app/dashboard', { replace: true });
}

return (
    <div>
        <Button className="button is-large" onClick={onClick}>
            <span className="icon is-medium">
                <i className="fas fa-user" />
            </span>
        </Button>
    </div>
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ternary expressions are for assignment. But you're not assigning to anything.

Swich to

```
if (authUser.roles.includes(ROLES.ANON)) {
  openSignin();
} else {
  openDashboard();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the rule in your [config file](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#using-configuration-files), disable the rule on the top of the page

```js
/* eslint no-unused-expressions: "off" */
```

or you can disable it for one line

```js
code // eslint-disable-line no-unused-expressions
```

or

```js
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-expressions
```

Note: `no-unused-expressions` is the error that you are getting